# Загрузка нескольких фото за одно сообщение в твиттер

Tags: oauth, twitter, twitter-api

Сделал скрипт для постинга в *твиттер*.

Загрузка фото и постинг с 1 фото работает корректно.

Когда пытаюсь сохранить в *твит* два фото, вылезает ошибка

> #32 - Could not authenticate you.

наверно, подпись неверно формируется, строка для подписи в итоге такая:

> "POST&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2F1.1%2Fstatuses%2Fupdate.json&media_ids%3D621261426717225984%2C621262420605362177%26oauth_consumer_key%3DTDVd28MwMgFgwHJLw2ShsTsJZ%26oauth_nonce%3Dea2244a0695898b423134b9c2a062203%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1436955300%26oauth_token%3D552572069-3l0F5YTIozo6OGli8SOGhTJ8DY1yt0oMqCVya4aO%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26status%3Dtest"
>
> post data: "status=test&media_ids=621261426717225984,621262420605362177"

не могу разобраться, что не так...

Comment: Лучше было бы закомментить токен и вообще авторизационные данные в пост-запросе.

Comment: эти данные естественно не реальные.

Comment: Кстати, а на чем код? Может, там ошибка в вызове и/или построении запроса, а не oauth. Да и искать ответ через enSO будет проще.

Answer (score 2):

сам уже разобрался. После двух дней мучений, выяснилось что в строке для подписи, media_ids должны быть через запятую которая в urlencode (%2C), и потом это все еще раз в urlencode, т.е. получается что фото объединены через %252C (urlencode(%2C)). Что абсолютно не клеится с документацией, где написано что это они должны быть через запятую.

вопрос закрыт.